# SQL to get only a certain number of items per category

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a pivot table grouped by the column `country` and for each `country` I want to get the first 1000 results. How would I do this using a `SELECT *` statement? It would be the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE country='a' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE country='b' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000 UNION ALL
...etc.
```

Is there a way to do this with something like window functions or something else instead? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY id) <= 1000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are in the right track. I'll use a common table expression and then just select the rows where row_num is under 1000

```
WITH numbered_rows AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY id) AS row_num
    FROM
        country
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    numbered_rows
WHERE
    row_num <= 1000;
```

Comment: yea that's it, thank you. You can even use the `QUALIFY` expression in place of the where clause if the sql dialect supports that.